# Will formatting C: drive make invisible folders on E: drive visible?

Tags: windows-7

Some of the folders of E: drive are in a hidden folder, so after formatting C: drive, will the hidden folders be visible or not?

Comment: What would be the relation between anything on C: and anything on E:?  What circumstances or details would lead you to raise the question?  You need to provide some background and detail so someone can understand the nature of your concern.  It isn't obvious what that is.

Comment: And how exactly is this folder hidden?

Answer (score 1):

> Some of the folders of E: drive are in a hidden folder, so after
>   formatting C: drive, will the hidden folders be visible or not?

File and folder permissions are retained on a file system level and are not connected to the main OS. The only thing that might be an issue is if the E: drive had ACLs connected to them, but I believe that would only come into play if the system was a file server and the user permissions changed with the new system install on the C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the files between E: an C: are linked making changes to either the C: or E: should not effect the other drives.